# Im getting this constructor error while deploying on hardhat local deployment chain

Tags: hardhat-deploy

While deploying my smart contract using hardhat hat I got this error
[image]

my github repo
https://github.com/yash-2138/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your github repo.. you have marked your Raffle contract as abstract So it does not take any parameters in the constructor..

soln:

1. remove abstract keyword in raffle contract
2. fullfillrandomWords function is misspelled in your contract

Edit: fixed the issue and raised a pull request in your repo..